# Code doesn't play nice when uploaded to Server [HTML,CSS,JS] [Error: Server stopped responding]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my [temporary] website: greenpen.web44.net

It's a basic chat web app i made, I've uploaded much larger websites before so i don't think I'm doing anything wrong there. I'm wondering if i might have some JS that may be messing up.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://www.codehelper.io/api/ips/?js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jQuery.js"></script>
<title>Instant Messenger</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
<body>
    <div class="Talk">
<ul>
<li>John: Hey</li>
<li>How are you?</li>
</ul>
</div>
<form>
    <div class="Messages">
Message: <input type="text" id="Message" size="100px">
<input type="submit" id="submit">
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

(Don't think the CSS would matter here)

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit").click(function(e){
//alert(codehelper_ip.IP);
//alert(codehelper_ip.CityName);
e.preventDefault();
var Input = $("#Message").val();
//alert(Input);
$(".Talk ul").append('<li>'+'['+ codehelper_ip.CityName +'~'+codehelper_ip.IP+']'+Input+'</li>');
            $("#Message").val("");
        });
    setInterval(main,500);
    });

    function main(){
        var count = $(".Talk li").length;
        if(count >= 20 ){
            //alert("20th");
             $(".Talk li").remove();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what the problem is. It looks like it's working as expected. You call main() on submit and on 'ready' which then removes all of your 'li's once the count === 20

Comment: Code works perfectly offline, but when I upload it to a server it is telling me that the "server is not responding".

Comment: Code looks fine to me. Could be a server issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible explanations:

- Your server is having intermittent issues unrelated to your development
- You are using a shared hosting provider running security software that is misidentifying some part of your code as malicious, blocking the page from being served
- You are hitting your host's request limit while testing your page and being temporarily blocked
- Your remote server is somehow misconfigured (possibly an htaccess issue) and simply cannot serve up that page

I hope somehow this helps, but with so few details, it's hard to say what the issue could be. Try launching developer tools in your favorite browser and seeing how the server's responding under the Network tab.